# Java - JUnit Test case for JDBC Connection - Oracle

Tags: junit

I m writing junit test cases for JDBC connection for Oracle (OJDBC6.jar). Below is my code

```
public void insertCard(){
Properties prop= new Properties();
properties.put("user","user");
properties.put("password","password");
properties.put("driver","com.oracle.OracleDriver")
 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection ( 
         "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl",properties);
      PreparedStatement insertCardValues = con.prepareStatement(
         "insert into card values(?,?,?)");
      
      insertCardValues.setInt(1,123);
      insertCardValues.setName(2,"Raja");
      insertCardValues.setAddress(3, "Lucknow");
      insertCardValues.executeUpdate();
}
}
```

Can someone help me to test below code

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection ( 
         "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl","properties);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, first of all I'd suggest to you to separate concerns.

1. Create a separate object which it should be the responsible of returning to you a Connection. Maybe you could create your own Connection wrapper object to deal with the SQL Connection
2. Then the class which is using the responsible of inserting the card, can retrieve an opened connection in order to create statements.
3. Do not forget also to have a method to release the connection once the insertCard logic is finished (no matter if it was succeeded or not, **is dangerous to leave opened connections against a database**)

Once you have refactored your code, you could easily cover it with unit tests using Mockito. But firstly I think you need to do a refactor, testing otherwise will be painful